Does Blender have a way to reset the interface in session?
Sometimes when I'm teaching people how to use Blender, I find that they accidentally enable snapping or change some setting by pressing the wrong key or change their transform orientation. Is there a key you can press or menu option that lets you reset the interface back to the defaults?  I don't mean doing a factory reset of preferences, I mean just changing any settings you might have changed in session to the point where Blender was when you loaded the program to work on the current scene.  If it doesn't have that, I think it really needs that feature for new and experienced users.  Maybe an add-on?

I mean, part of learning Blender is learning how to debug and avoid accidentally altering those settings. It's just an inevitability that you spend the first few days accidentally enabling snapping, or getting lost in the viewport or whatever. It happens. Eventually you learn the ropes and those issues become less frequent. You could probably write an addon to do this but what Snap settings, Transform orientation etc is considered "default" differs from user to user. Not to mention there's no way of knowing what settings a beginner might wind up accidentally changing until they do so.

If this is an extreme issue and you're teaching a large class of kids or something then I would consider breaking these individual "issues" into their own lesson plan. Like make a 30 minute lesson exclusively about Viewport navigation Ortho vs. Persp view modes etc. Next lesson dive into a "mini-game" about snapping modes etc. You might be trying to get straight to "How to model a whole scene/object" a bit too fast. IDK. I understand the concern but I think it could be viewed as a teaching opportunity, rather than applying a band-aid fix to the issue.

in the User Preferences there is the checkbox Load & Save > Blend Files > [X] Load UI. If you uncheck it, then Blender keeps the current UI layout (workspace, views, etc) when you load a blend file. To "reset" the UI settings, save the file with the messy UI, then load a blend file where the UI settings are ok. Now deactivate the Load UI checkbox and load the file with the messy UI settings again. It should be fine now.

+Blunder Thanks for providing a solution. It's a bit complex, but it works.  However, this method only resets some of the settings, it still keeps the grid snap, proportional editing, etc. turned on.
